# How do I configure my Eclipse project to use the log4j 1.2 to 2.16 bridge

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, log4j, bridge

I am trying to use the log4j 1.2 to 2.16 bridge - log4j-1.2-api-2.16.0.jar

I thought that by using the bridge jar I would not have to change my code.

I am using these three jars in my classpath:
log4j-1.2-api-2.16.0.jar
log4j-core-2.16.0.jar
log4j-api-2.16.0.jar

In the Eclipse project properties *Java Build Path, Libraries* tab, I see:

```
Modulepath  
  >log4j-1.2-api-2.16.0.jar - Log4jBridgeExample/lib  
  >log4j-api-2.16.0.jar - Log4jBridgeExample/lib  
  >log4j-core-2.16.0.jar - Log4jBridgeExample/lib  
  >JRE System Library [JavaSE-9]  
  Classpath
```

Here is the the one class definition.

```
    package test;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    public class MyClass {
        //Here we use old log4j syntax like exists in thousands 
        //of other classes in our other projects. 
        private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            logger.info("Howdy");
        }
    }
```

When I run it, I get the following runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger
    at Log4jBridgeExample/test.MyClass.<clinit>(MyClass.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: It seems that `log4j-api` is not in your _"Build path"_.

Comment: Updated question to show Build Path, Libraries setting.